# Running unit tests on static functions

Tags: c, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I need to test several functions that are defined as static in a file(not used anywhere outside this file except in the unit test).

To enable the unit test file to see the functions I tried using an .h file in which these functions are declared, however this results in a linkage error.
A solution I considered is, instead of using the static keyword, using a macro that is replace by static in the working version an is empty in the unit test version.

However I don't know how to make the condition dependent on the startup project instead of manually redefining macro all the time.Seeing as the code is intended to run on a TI processor I also considered using a wrapper function that is only compiled under when WIN32 is defined.

I would very much like to hear feedback on these ideas and better ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the linkage error you get, might help others help you.

Comment: Just use non-static funtions? Fiddling with macros etc is just not worth it

Answer (score 4):

In your source file you need

```
#ifndef UNITTESTS
    #define STATIC
#else
    #define STATIC static
#endif
```

Then when you build your unit tests pass`-DUNITTESTS` to make

Otherwise consider including your source file in your tests, i.e.

```
#include "file.c"
```

Comment: I'm no fan of the macro solution because it requires modifying your code. Both by defining an extra macro, and testing a code that is (slightly) different from the real one. Think of a possible compiler bug on the interpretation of the static keyword